# How to check a Date Range whether is a full calendar month?

Tags: java, date

I am trying to check if a date range like 1/1/2014-1/15/2014 covering a full calendar month (for the month that the range is in it). My range is always a full or less than a full calendar month. 
My problem is to find a quick way to get the full calendar month range based on the the month that I already have in my range and then I can compare them to see if they are the same or not. Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Quick hints: If the first date does not start on the first of the month, it's not a full range. If it does, then all you need to do is to get the number of days within the current month and check if the second date's day equals the number of days in the month. You can do it. If possible, try to use the "new" time package's classes: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html It makes life easier.

Comment: Do you mean that you need to know that *1/1/2014-1/15/2014* doesn't cover the whole month while *1/1/2014-1/31/2014* does?

Comment: Please show your code so we have some of idea of what you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

You have inputs:

1. Range Start date (rsd)
2. Range End Date (red)
3. Input Date (id)

Use [compareTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29) method:

```
if(id.compareTo(rsd) >= 0 && id.compareTo(red) <= 0)
    return true; // id is in range
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add(int,%20int)) class. 
Just add one day to the upper limit(if the day is >=28) and you can check if the month has changed.

This should also work for leap years.

The lower limit should of course be the first day of the month (1/1/2014) :-).

*Note I am not sure of what you really want. This should be the way to check that your interval covers the whole month.*

Comment: Don't recommend the old date/time APIs. They're terrible. Use the new `java.time` API.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström sorry. I still have to work with older versions of JDK so tend to forget brand new solutions even when they are really worth it. Nevertheless, some people may have the same constraint

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

Avoid the old date-time classes. Use the java.time classes built into Java 8 and later.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class is for date-only values without time-of-day.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of( 2016 , 2 , 1 ) ;
LocalDate stop = start.plusDays( 15 ) ;
```

First use [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) to make sure they are in same month at all.

```
Boolean inSameMonth = YearMonth.from( start ).equals( YearMonth.from( stop ) ) ;
```

If same month, then move on to see if they are make up a full month. Check two criteria:

- If start is the first of month
- if stop is last day of same month as start.

Combine into one line, or break it up to be more readable.

```
Boolean isFullMonth = ( start.getDayOfMonth() == 1 ) && YearMonth.from( start ).atEndOfMonth().equals( stop ) ;
```